# AngularJS 1.2 to 1.3 migration issue - [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: angularjs, migration

I am trying to migrate my angularjs 1.2 app (which is working fine now) to angularjs 1.3. But I am getting the below error.

> [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module constructionApp due
>   to: TypeError: Unable to get property 'push' of undefined or null
>   reference    at Anonymous function (http://localhost/app/app.js:33:5)

Also, this is the code I am having in my app.js

```
var cmApp = angular.module('myApp',
        ['xeditable', 'ui.bindonce', 'gantt', 'angularFileUpload', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.router', 'ngAnimate', 'wc.Directives']); 

cmApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) { 

var interceptor = ['$rootScope', '$q', '$location', function (scope, $q, $location) {

    function success(response) {
        return response;
    }

    function error(response) {
        var status = response.status;
        if (status == 401 || status == 404) {
             $location.path('#/Error');
            return;
        }
        // otherwise
        return $q.reject(response);

    }

    return function (promise) {
        return promise.then(success, error);
    }

}];
$httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(interceptor); ***get error at this line

// For any unmatched url, redirect to /home
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/Home");

$stateProvider
      .state('home', {
          url: "/home",
          templateUrl: "/app/views/home.html",
          controller: "homeController"
      })
.state('somepage', {
        url: "/somepage/:ID",
        templateUrl: "/app/views/somepage.html",
        controller: "somePageController"
    })
});
```

Please help me to solve this migration issue.

Comment: use DI to declare config `cmApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider',function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {//your code goes here }])`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternative of $httpProvider.responseInterceptors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23804981/alternative-of-httpprovider-responseinterceptors)